# Auth0 - How to Trust and Save User Information on a Custom API or Backend?

Tags: node.js, express, security, authentication, auth0

I'm trying to figure out how to 'trust' user information (things like name, email, and `sub` claim) on my API server for a react native application. I've followed the official react native quick start guide by auth0 here:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/

and I've seen iterations of this 4 or 5 ways across the web. Yes it's great, we have a frontend authentication method - where we get an `id_token` and `access_token` returned to us in the frontend. The `access_token` is fine and I understand that totally, i.e. I save it to local storage on the device, add it to the `Authorization` header, and use a jwt middleware to protect routes (also provided by auth0 on the custom APIs page):

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var jwks = require('jwks-rsa');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var jwtCheck = jwt({
      secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
          cache: true,
          rateLimit: true,
          jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
          jwksUri: 'https://<myauth0domain>/.well-known/jwks.json'
    }),
    audience: '<myapiendpoing>',
    issuer: '<myauth0domain>',
    algorithms: ['RS256']
});

app.use(jwtCheck);

app.get('/authorized', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Secured Resource');
});

app.listen(port);
```

Now finally to where I am stuck: with respect to the `id_token`, *how do I save any user ID information to my server and trust that it is really that user?* I want to save things like their name and email since my app also has a user settings table where users can change their profile information.

Surely I can't just forward the `id_token` along to use as a 'trusted' identity server-side. The moment there is a connection step between auth0 server, then the device, and then my API, a bad actor could spoof the values in the `id_token` - it is, after all, just JSON.

My current solution is calling auth0's built-in `/userinfo` endpoint from my backend - you pass the `access_token` and get the user info back, but obviously this isn't very performant. To try and avoid performance issues, I do this once to setup the account information, and then use the `sub` claim (which is the user ID) from the `access_token` to identify who the user is in any later user settings related endpoints. The `sub` claim can be trusted *after* it passes the JWT middleware, right?

The only other solution I could think of was changing the authorization callback URI on my react app to an endpoint on my API, and NOT to a URI leading back to the react native app, but then I think that means implementing the whole user session and passport story in express. Perhaps I have to do this anyway if I want to do any user-based action on the API?

They say that OAuth makes things a lot easier, but at this point, I am just really really confused on trusting if the user is really who they say they are server-side. In fact, what is even the point of having the `id_token` on the UI side? From my understanding, the values in `id_token` can only be 'trusted' for purely display purposes. You could never use them as identifying key(s) in requests to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a [Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) flow. In this flow, you generate a code verifier and challenger and receive a one-time use code that can be used to get an auth token, refresh token, and id token. This request can be done on the client side.

Using this one-time use code we can make a second request, the one for the actual tokens, from our own servers. Since this request takes place from your trusted server (not on the client, nor does Auth0 let you make the request on the client!) we can trust that the contents of the id token returned have not been tampered with. (i.e. it is a machine-to-machine connection from your API server to Auth0)

This is also an excellent point in time to see if the user exists already (and if not generate a server-side account or user information using the id token's contents). In an ideal situation, the user has to only authenticate once (thus hitting this endpoint once), and we can for all times after continually renew authorization tokens with the refresh token that we have saved securely with their account.

The only exception is if the refresh token itself expires, in which we ask them to authenticate again.

---

EDIT:

For the *very* curious, I ran into an additional, though slightly unrelated problem when implementing PKCE specifically with React Native Expo projects. The solution to that issue can be viewed [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/react-native-with-expo-oauth-token-endpoint-always-results-in-access-denied-in-pkce-flow/48145) and [here](https://chrisfrew.in/blog/auth0-expo-and-react-native-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce/).